# How to deserialize it?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, deserialization

```json
{
  "success": true,
  "time": 1668509701,
  "currency": "RUB",
  "items": {
    "186150629_143865972": {
      "price": "278.61",
      "buy_order": 251.72,
      "avg_price": "284.900000",
      "popularity_7d": "10",
      "market_hash_name": "CS:GO Case Key",
      "ru_name": "Ключ от кейса CS:GO",
      "ru_rarity": "базового класса",
      "ru_quality": "",
      "text_color": "D2D2D2",
      "bg_color": ""
    },
    "36150629_143865972": {
      "price": "278.61",
      "buy_order": 251.72,
      "avg_price": "284.900000",
      "popularity_7d": "10",
      "market_hash_name": "CS:GO Case Key",
      "ru_name": "Ключ от кейса CS:GO",
      "ru_rarity": "базового класса",
      "ru_quality": "",
      "text_color": "D2D2D2",
      "bg_color": ""
    },
  }
}
```

Don't go out and create a class structure for deserialization via JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
Nested entities 186150629_143865972 may be different, their structure is always the same, but the names are unique.

I'm trying to do something like this but it doesn't work...

```cs
public class Item
{
    public string price { get; set; }
    public double buy_order { get; set; }
    public string avg_price { get; set; }
    public string popularity_7d { get; set; }
    public string market_hash_name { get; set; }
    public string ru_name { get; set; }
    public string ru_rarity { get; set; }
    public string ru_quality { get; set; }
    public string text_color { get; set; }
    public string bg_color { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public int time { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Which serialiser are you using? JSON.Net or System.Text.Json?

Comment: Your `items` needs to be a `Dictionary<string, Item>`, not a `List`.

Comment: You should probably also put `[JsonProperty("PROPERTY_NAME")]` in front of or above each property (replace the PROPERTY_NAME with the name in your JSON)

Comment: "It doesn't work" is *never* enough information. *Always* describe what happens, and how that differs to what you want to happen.

Comment: If any answer works for you - please mark it as accepted one (checkmark to the left of it). And take [tour]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your *json*, the `items` property should be a *dictionary*, not a *list*.

```
public class Root
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public int time { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Item> items { get; set; } = new();
 }
```

Also, another thing I would mention is that *properties* should be capitalized (see naming conventions in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions)) and combined with `JsonProperty` attribute.

```
[JsonProperty("market_hash_name")] 
public string MarketHashName { get; set; }
```

instead of

```
public string market_hash_name { get; set; }
```